# Activate a CSS flip transition

Tags: javascript, onclick, transition

I have been following Adam Khoury's tutorial on how to make a 3d flip animation which works fine with the hover pseudo class but I'm struggling to activate the transition with java script. My aim is to click the box to activate the transition.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W3eJWpvIl0g

```
Html:

                                <div class="flip3D" >
                <div class="back">Box 1 - Back</div> 
                <div class="front"  >Box 1 - Front</div> 
                </div> 

                <div class="flip3D">
                <div class="back">Box 2 - Back</div> 
                <div class="front">Box 2 - Front</div>
                </div> 

                <div class="flip3D"> 
                <div class="back">Box 3 - Back</div>
                <div class="front">Box 3 - Front</div>



CSS:

.flip3D{ width:240px; height:200px; margin:10px; float:left; }

 .flip3D > .front{ position:absolute; -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 0deg );
 transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 0deg );
 background:#FC0; width:240px; height:200px; border-radius: 7px;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; backface-visibility: hidden;
 transition: -webkit-transform .5s linear 0s; transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
 }

 .flip3D > .back{ position:absolute; -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 180deg );
 transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 180deg );
 background: #80BFFF; width:240px; height:200px; border-radius: 7px; -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; backface-visibility: hidden;
 transition: -webkit-transform .5s linear 0s;
 transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
 }

 .flip3D:active> .front{
 -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( -180deg );
 transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( -180deg );
 }
 .flip3D:active > .back{
 -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 0deg ); 
 transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 0deg ); }
```

Thank you!

Comment: just use .addClass() : http://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery for that. And trigger the hover event once you click on the box.

Try this

```
$('.box').click(function () {
  $('.animationElement').trigger('hover');
}
```

This would activate the hover event for the element. More over CSS would take action here and would trigger the animation.

Or you can use a className for that and append the classname to the element.

```
$('.box').click(function () {
  $('.animationElement').attr('class', 'flip3D');
}
```

Then CSS would do the job.